# counting number of element in a set of integer array without using stl

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to write a program to count total number of integer elements from scratch without using any built in function,
I tried something like;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int arr[]={2,4,6,8};
int count=0;
while(true){
    if(arr[count]==arr[-1])
       break;
       count++;
 }
 cout<<count<<endl;
}
```

but the above code outputs a wrong value without leaving any error, please suggest me program for doing such operation.

Comment: *I want to write a program to count total number of integer elements* -- The compiler knows how many items without having to write any loop.  Also, where did you get the idea that there is a mystery `-1` element in an array?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie agreed sir, i know my code is going wrong due to mystery [-1] which works in python but not in cpp, was looking program from scratch as program to count character element from scratch can be built,so got idea to write for integer as well

Comment: C++ is not Python.  Do not use Python (or any other language) as a guide in writing C++.  The only thing you will accomplish by trying to make C++ look like Python is 1) Make the C++ buggy, 2) Make it inefficient or 3) Make the program look weird to a real C++ programmer.  You are accomplishing item 3).

Comment: C++ in general built in size member that denotes the size or any other way to determine the array size, that is unless the compiler has access to the size of the array via the type at that point. In this case you're lucky and it does (see the answer), but in general you cannot rely on this and this is why you usually pass size info in addition to the array to functions (preferrably in a struct/class; `std::array` may be a choice here).If you try to apply the approach presented in the answer to the parameter of a function`void f(int[] array)`in the function body,the approach below doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = (int) sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
```

is a no loop solution and doesn't need stl. [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

Comment: Thank you dude, i am looking for solution that is visible to me & don't want to use built in function sizeof

Comment: [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-size-of-array-in-cc-without-using-sizeof-operator/) can be helpful.

Comment: None of this works if the array is passed to a function.